# Single Page Applications and Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a client who wants a tag to fire on a thank you page but have users come from a form fill on a previous page. I've tried all types of set ups but none of them work 100 percent. The only thing I know is that the client site is a single page application which does not support the refer variable. The option that semi-worked leverages the history change trigger type however the client needs to track people who uniquely submitted the form fill page and made it to the thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

The best option here would be adding a dataLayer.push to the successful form submission callback. That is, if the form is submitted via JS.

If it's just a standard (legacy) html form submission, then GTM has listeners for those. But they're rare, especially on SPAs.

If adding a dataLayer.push seems too complex, well then use the thank you page (with the history change) in conjunction with a short-lived cookie to prevent double firing, but it's a hack and not without bugs.